# AWK Unix command conversion to PowerShell

Tags: powershell, awk

I would like to ask help in how to convert the line below to a PowerShell command.

```
awk 'BEGIN{OFS=FS=","}$15==1{$15=$13"="$14}{print > "AJB_AWK"}'
```

I have a comma delimited file (no header) and what I need to do is to check if the 15th field is 1. If it is, I need to convert it with the value of column 13 "=" column 14. I already did a research but could not find the right commands to make it work.

Answer (score 1):

The cmdlets you're looking for are [`Import-Csv`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/import-csv?view=powershell-3.0), [`Export-Csv`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/export-csv?view=powershell-3.0), and [`ForEach-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/foreach-object?view=powershell-3.0). Normally you wouldn't reference CSV fields by index in PowerShell, but by the actual field/column name. If your file doesn't have headers you can define them yourself via the `-Header` parameter of `Import-Csv`.

```
$headers = 'h01', ..., 'h13', 'h14', 'h15', ...
(Import-Csv 'C:\path\to\input.csv' -Header $headers) | ForEach-Object {
    if ($_.h15 -eq 1) {
        $_.h15 = '{0}={1}' -f $_.h13, $_.h14
    }
    $_   # output record back to pipeline
} | Export-Csv 'C:\path\to\output.csv' -NoType
```

Replace `h##` with appropriate column names. Alternatively you could also use numbers (e.g. `$headers = 1..20`). The number of columns can be determined from the first line of the file:

```
$cols = ((Get-Content 'C:\path\to\input.csv' -TotalCount 1) -split ',').Count
$headers = 1..$cols
```

Answer (score 0):

Other method, with get-content for take brut file and split with ',' delimiter

```
$yourpathfile="c:\temp\yourfile.txt"

(get-content $yourpathfile | %{

  $row=$_ -split ','

  if ($row[14] -eq '1')
  {
      $result=$row[0..13], ("{0}={1}" -f $row[12], $row[13])  , $row[15.. ($row.Length) ]
  }
  else
  {
      $result=$row
  }

  $result -join ','

}) | Set-Content $yourpathfile
```